# How to add a class path in vimscript

Tags: junit, vim

I'm working on a simple vim script that will allow me to hit F6 and run a single jUnit test for some java class.

So far I can get JUnit to work from the command line with this

```
java -cp "/c/junit/junit.jar" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

But when I attempt to add this in my vim script it appears the class path string isn't recognized. How should I add this -cp value in the script itself?

(what I have so far)

```
function RunTest()
    let cla = matchstr(expand("%:p"), '^.*[/\\]src[/\\]\(test\|java\)[/\\]\zs.*')
    let class = 'java -cp "/c/junit/junit.jar" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ' .  strpart(substitute(cla, "/", "\.", "g"), 0, strlen(cla) -5)
    if match(class, "Test") == -1
        let class = class . "Test"
    endif
endfunction

map <F6> <Esc>:echo RunTest()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I just needed to escape my inside " with a \

```
let class = "java -cp \"c:/junit/junit.jar;./\" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore fullpackagename.MyClassTest"
```